# How to do long scroll menu with level selection ?

Tags: android, android-layout, user-interface

And many thanks for your help on this !

I would like to do an application where the main menu is like a long (very long) scroll view with some buttons to select different levels. The goal is to have custom buttons for level and custom styles for each part of the menu (like different worlds).

But I don't know how to do this easily (maybe) and efficiently (for sure) ? I though about a long ScrollView, but the performance could be really poor. Or about a ListView / GridView with a very custom style ?

Do you think it is needed to include a full game engine to achieve this ? Even the rest of my app does not need it ?

I found some inspiration apps which already use those kinds of menu :

[image]
[HeadSpace App](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mES9d.png) 
[image]
[Score! Hero Game](https://i.stack.imgur.com/keyw4.jpg)

Or even a less styled one :

[image]
[DuoLingo App](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Iedt5.jpg)

Thank you so much for your ideas, and hints on this !

Have a nice coding day !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think this is a very personal question and decision; I mean: this depends on you, your preferences for your own game, is not a technical question. Personally I like your designs, but I think that "a long (very long) scroll view" could be slow and too heavy for the player. Think on the [game experience](http://www.gamasutra.com/blogs/DouglasLynn/20120830/176837/What_Is_The_Game_Experience.php), and the way you make it easier to interact for the gamer. That solution would be so slow to get the last levels, almost irritating. IMO, it is better to have one button for each world, and each of them guides the player to the levels inside that world. There you can use a GridView, customizing that, ordering buttons on zig-zag... But this is if you can repeat the levels or replay them; if is necesary to have that. If it is not necesary I woudn't show that as main menu.

Again, this is a very personal question and decision, not technical; and here people like me can give you a subjective opinion. It all depends on your preferences.

Comment: Woaw ! I didn't see such answers coming... And I am very glad that you did ! I didn't think about this menu the way you did and indeed you are perfectly right ! I found this long scroll view fun and useful, but with you point of view I have to admit that I was wrong.
Thanks a lot for your answer, very interesting ! Have a nice day !